# Python need help figuring inclusive

Tags: python, string

Full disclosure, I am in school and I missed a problem on codingbat assignment 2 weeks ago, I am hoping I can get some direction here so that I can learn for the future

my problem was 
Given a string and an int n, return a string made of the first n characters of the string, followed by the first n-1 characters of the string, inclusive (i.e. 0 <= n and n <= len(str)).

```
d_2('ydu', 2) → 'ydy'
d_2('yoda', 3) → 'yod'
d_2('yoda', 1) → '1'
```

The farthest I could get was:

```
def d_2(string, n):
  string = string[:-n:]
  return string
```

## this would return 2 right answers

## if I did

```
def d_2(string, n):
  string = string[:-n:10]
  return string
```

## it would return 3 right answers.

I am sure it is a very simple thing, but my brain just is not picking it out, any direction

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a loop to construct the string `a = string[:n-1] + string[:n-2] + string[:n-3] ....` until `n` is equal to 0.

```
def echo_first(string, n):
    a=''
    while n > 0:
        a += string[:n]
        n -= 1
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Recursive Functions to call the function itself until `n==1`:

```
def echo_first(string, n):
    return string[:1] if n==1 else string[:n]+echo_first(string, n-1)
```